# azure pipeline - powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

im just trying to do the simplest pipeline in the world.

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
     Write-Output abcde > abc.txt
     $letters = Get-Content .\abc.txt 
     write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=json]$letters"
     write-host $(json)
```

But in the console im not seeing the output `abcde`

what im doing wrong ?

im in purpose added the          `write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=json]$letters"` so i will be able to use the variable `json` laster

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you can not use a variable TFS on the same stage at which it created.
Your code works fine, to test run:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 1
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Output abcde > abc.txt
      $letters = Get-Content .\abc.txt
      write-host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=json]$letters"
      write-host $(json)
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      write-host $(json)
```

Comment: If the answer helped you, please mark it as correct.